# How to move all values of the same ID to a new column provided if one of the value is greater than 5 in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling with a problem in R. I'm trying to move all values in RL column of the same ID in Trial column into a new column, provided that any of the value in RL column is greater than 5.

I have a data set like this:

```
dt <- tibble(
  TRIAL = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  RL = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 2, 3, 1),
  SL = c(1, 1.5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1.5, 0)
)

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   TRIAL    RL    SL
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         1   1  
# 2 A         2   1.5
# 3 A         3   1  
# 4 B         1   0  
# 5 B         6   0  
# 6 B         3   1  
# 7 C         2   1  
# 8 C         3   1.5
# 9 C         1   0
```

This is what I want to achieve: I want all values from one column in a group to be moved to a new column if the max value for that group is greater than 5, see example below.

```
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#   TRIAL    RL    SL  RLCT
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         1   1      NA
# 2 A         2   1.5    NA
# 3 A         3   1      NA
# 4 B        NA   0       1
# 5 B        NA   0       6
# 6 B        NA   1       3
# 7 C         2   1      NA
# 8 C         3   1.5    NA
# 9 C         1   0      NA
```

When I run this code I get not the expected output

```
dt %>% group_by("TRIAL") %>% mutate(RLCT = case_when ("RL"> 5 ~ "RL"))

# # A tibble: 9 x 5
# # Groups:   "TRIAL" [1]
#   TRIAL    RL    SL `"TRIAL"` RLCT 
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <chr>
# 1 A         1   1   TRIAL     RL   
# 2 A         2   1.5 TRIAL     RL   
# 3 A         3   1   TRIAL     RL   
# 4 B         1   0   TRIAL     RL   
# 5 B         6   0   TRIAL     RL   
# 6 B         3   1   TRIAL     RL   
# 7 C         2   1   TRIAL     RL   
# 8 C         3   1.5 TRIAL     RL   
# 9 C         1   0   TRIAL     RL
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also please share your attempts that failed

Comment: You're comparing the string "RL" with the number 5, which doesn't make sense. `dplyr` functions generally take columns as bare names, not strings--same applies to your `group_by` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure not the most straightforward solution but seems to work:

```
dt0 <- dt %>%
  mutate(RLCT = NA) %>%
  group_by(TRIAL) %>%
  filter(!any(RL > 5))
dt %>%
  group_by(TRIAL) %>%
  filter(any(RL > 5)) %>%
  mutate(RLCT = RL) %>%
  rbind(dt0, .) %>%
  mutate(RL = ifelse(!is.na(RLCT), NA, RL))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   TRIAL [3]
  TRIAL    RL    SL  RLCT
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1   1      NA
2 A         2   1.5    NA
3 A         3   1      NA
4 C         2   1      NA
5 C         3   1.5    NA
6 C         1   0      NA
7 B        NA   0       1
8 B        NA   0       6
9 B        NA   1       3
```

Add `(arrange(TRIAL))` for alphabetic ordering